# Что-то не пойму с Distinct

Tags: c#, linq

Пытаюсь избавится от повторов сравнивая по конкретному полю объекта
Взял код из MSDN немного изменив

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product[] products = {
            new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 },
            new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 },
            new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 },
            new Product { Name = "lemon", Code = 12 },
            new Product { Name = "lemon", Code = 32 },
            new Product { Name = "lemon", Code = 9 }};

        IEnumerable<Product> noduplicates =
            products.Distinct(new ProductComparer());

        foreach (var product in noduplicates)
            Console.WriteLine(product.Name + " " + product.Code);
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
    }

    class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
    {         
        public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
        {   
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;                             
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;

            return x.Code == y.Code;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Product product)
        {             
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;

            int hashProductName = product.Name == null ? 0 : product.Name.GetHashCode();                
            int hashProductCode = product.Code.GetHashCode();

            return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
        }
    }
```

Так вот если ставить точку прерывания на Equals, то попадаешь туда только один раз на сравнении Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }. Соответственно и результат не совсем ожидаемый, отбрасывается только один из Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }
Пример надуманный естественно. Просто непонятно почему Distinct не вызывается для всех объектов?! Как оно вообще работает?!

Comment: Я вот не знал как работает `IEqualityComparer<T>`, но ваш пример прекрасно это показал. Объекты сравниваются  по хэшкоду, и только в случае коллизии вызывается `Equals`

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно написали в комментарии, сравнивать объекты - дело затратное, поэтому сначала сравнивается хэш-код объектов и если он разный, то объекты сразу же считаются разными. Если же хэш-код объектов совпал, то только тогда сравниваются собственно объекты (потому что у хэш-кода бывают коллизии - одинаковые значения при разном значении объектов). Обратная ситуация, когда хэш-код разный, а объекты при этом одинаковые - невозможна в силу детерминированности функции вычисления хэш-кода по объекту.